# Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

this method running always. I checked with API. If API value change I delete my database and insert again. Is that right way to use like this scenario? (can use streamWidget or FutureWidget? If can How? )

Error message:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception:
>   RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

```
 checkQuick(String url, String token) async {
    result =
        (await HelperDatabase1().displayGetUserPreference()).elementAt(0)?.data;
    final response = await http.get(
      '$url/nativeapi/v1.0/User/GetUserPreference',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
    );
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    GetUserPreference model = GetUserPreference.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    var data = GetUserPreference(data: model.data);

    if (result != data.data) {
      await HelperDatabase1().deleteGetUserPreference();
      await HelperDatabase1().storeGetUserPreference(url, token);
    }
  }
```

Comment: it looks like `displayGetUserPreference` is returning an empty list

Comment: yes. you are right. How to handle null value proper way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because `displayGetUserPreference` returns an empty list, so in order to fix your issue you should check if the list is not empty before get the item.

```
final list =  (await HelperDatabase1().displayGetUserPreference());
if (list.isNotEmpty)
    result = list.elementAt(0).data;
```

Comment: new error: ```Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)```

Comment: coming from here, ```final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);```

Comment: print response.body before decode to check the result

Comment: I printed.. result is `null`

Comment: then something is wrong with your service :) you should check that and maybe add a validation if (response.body != null )  and add your code inside the condition, that's another issue,  the issue about your question was already solved :)

Comment: I added ```if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {}``` is now working without error

Answer (score 1):

If you are having such problem with flutter package [new_version](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version),:

1. Go to new_version.dart
2. Replace line 183 with: `(elm) => elm.text.contains('key: \'ds:5\''),`
3. Stop the debugging session, and start the app again.